# Hovering over menu items on a ListTile highlights the list item that contains it and does not go away

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, listview

With the following code below, when I click on the menu anchor button and hover my mouse over the menu items, the ListTile underneath it also gets highlighted. After that, toggling the menu off will still leave the ListTile "highlighted" and stays highlighted with no way of disabling it. How do I prevent that from happening?

[DartPad Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=24e653c5475584a74a9011ad0bc44ca4&null_safety=true&theme=light)

Also, how are you supposed to debug this behavior in VSCode?

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: tasks.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final task = tasks[index];
    return Material(
      key: Key(task.id.toString()),
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(task.name),
        onTap: () async {},
        trailing: MenuAnchor(
          menuChildren: menuItems
              .map(
                (item) => Material(
                  child: MenuItemButton(
                    child: Text(item),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          builder: (context, controller, child) => IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            onPressed: () {
              if (controller.isOpen) {
                controller.close();
              } else {
                controller.open();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Searching on the web and on the flutter repo for a mention of this behavior and I found none. I tried wrapping the `MenuItemButton` with `Material` but that didn't seem to help.

[image: Demo of ListView and menu item interaction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the focus is trapped in the `ListTile` once the menu item is highlighted. To debug this behavior, observe the focus change on each `ListTile` with the `onFocusChange` callback:

```dart
ListTile(
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    // ...
  },
)
```

---

I can think of three approaches to fix this.

1. Manage the focus node of the `ListTile`s manually so you can unfocus them
2. Use [`MenuBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuBar-class.html) instead of [`MenuAnchor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuAnchor-class.html)
3. Set the focus color of the `ListTile` to transparent

For the last approach, you would do

```dart
ListTile(
  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
  // ...
)
```

Comment: Hi @Dhafin Rayhan. Thank you, I think I was able to create a workaround to this problem by doing #1 from your suggestions. Basically what I did was to force the ListTile's focusNode to unfocus after closing the menu. I'm unsure if this is the correct approach at the moment since I also want to retain the focus back to the ListTile that contained the menu. I just want the focus highlight to go away after selecting another item.

BTW, I tried upvoting your answer but I only have 10 reputation points right now since I haven't had much activity here in StackOverflow. Sorry.